# When does Sitecore run the initialize pipeline?

Tags: sitecore

I have been peeking through the Sitecore.Kernel but can't seem to find the place where Sitecore runs the Initialize pipeline. Does it run on every page request or only once on application start? Can you point me to the exact place where the Run method is being called for this pipeline?

**update**
There reason I ended up asking this question is because I was tracing back, in Sitecore's code, the execution of the `mvc.requestBegin` pipeline. This is what I found:

- the `Initialize` pipeline runs the `InitializeRoutes` processor...
- `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes.Process(PipelineArgs args)`
  calls...
- `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes, PipelineArgs args)` calls...
- `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes.SetRouteHandlers(RouteCollection routes, PipelineArgs args)` creates new `RouteHandlerWrapper` objects

here things get a bit fuzzy...

- `Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHandlerWrapper.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)` returns `(IHttpHandler) new RouteHttpHandler`

and then, finally...

- `Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)` calls...
- `Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginRequest()` runs `mvc.requestBegin` pipeline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to try adding some debugging to a clean installation of Sitecore 7.2.
I created the following simple class:

```
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SCMVC72.Pipelines
{
    public class DebugStackTrace
    {
        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace(); 
            Log.Info(string.Empty, (object)this);
            Log.Info("*********************************************************************", (object)this);
            Log.Info("Debug StackTrace", (object)this);
            Log.Info(st.ToString(), (object)this);
            Log.Info("*********************************************************************", (object)this);
        }
    }
}
```

And the I added the following config file in the `App_Config\Include` folder:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="SCMVC72.Pipelines.DebugStackTrace, SCMVC72" 
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

On application restart, This is the output I got in the logs:

```
5764 14:38:08 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
5764 14:38:08 INFO  
5764 14:38:08 INFO  *********************************************************************
5764 14:38:08 INFO  Debug StackTrace
5764 14:38:08 INFO     at SCMVC72.Pipelines.DebugStackTrace.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start()
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
5764 14:38:08 INFO  *********************************************************************
```

Which was output right befor the famous:

```
5764 14:38:08 INFO  
5764 14:38:08 INFO  **********************************************************************
5764 14:38:08 INFO  **********************************************************************
5764 14:38:08 INFO  Sitecore started
5764 14:38:08 INFO  Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 140228)
```

This confirms what HRH John West said when he wrote that "this happens in one of the obfuscated assemblies" - Sitecore.Nexus, to be more precise.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `SetActiveSite` method in the `Sitecore.Context` class. This runs the `Intialize` pipeline, and there are a few places from which the method is called.

- `JobRunner.InitalizeContext`
- `MediaCreator.SetContext`
- `MediaRequestHandler.RedirectIfUserShouldBeLoggedIn`
- `WebDavMediaRequestHandler.ProcessRequest`

So it appears to be linked with initialization of a context, and therefore not just at the beginning of the application.

For information, I found this by searching for `"Initalize"` (with the quotes included), which found this:

```csharp
CorePipeline.Run("initialize", new PipelineArgs());
```

Comment: Now it would be interesting to now who calls the `InitializeContext` method and when. I am guessing then that, if `SetActiveSite` runs the `Initialize` pipeline, this means that the `HttpBeginRequest` pipeline must have run already (since that's the pipeline that determines the site, the context item, the user, etc.)

Comment: I had a quick look. It's called as part of the `Job` pipeline. Search for `InitializeContext` in the web.config

Comment: So it seems like it's the creation of an "artificial" context. This article alludes to it http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/using-sitecore-jobs/

Comment: Yep I just found that out as well. Stepping back for a second this whole investigation started from trying to understand who calls/when is called the `mvc.beginRequest` pipeline. I found out that it is called by `RouteHttpHandler.BeginRequest()` which is called by `RouteHandlerWrapper.GetHttpHandler()`, which is called during the execution of the `initialize` pipeline. Now I am finding that this happens whenever a job is run. But jobs are run in separate threads so I don't think this is the right execution path... Lost :)

Comment: :) I still don't believe that the `initialize` pipeline is executed only when jobs are executed. It contains too many important things both in the regular `web.config` definition and in the MVC configuration. I think there must be some other place where this is being called from.

Comment: HRH John west states `"<initialize>: Initializes the Sitecore application"`. http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/Important-Pipelines-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx In all likielhood, this happens in one of the obfuscated assemblies, so not much chance of tracking it down.

Comment: "HRH" :) So if that's true, does that mean that, following my trail which I just posted in my original question, the `mvc.requestBegin` pipeline is executed only once when the application start? This doesn't sound right, now does it?